# Why is my element not being appended to my array state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a simple todo app using React, which contains a text input area for the user, and an "ADD" button that when clicked, adds the user's text input to an ordered list underneath. Below is a part of my entire code that I believe pertains to this issue:

```
import React from "react";
import TextBar from "./TextBar";
import AddButton from "./AddButton";
import ListEntry from "./ListEntry";

class UserToDoInput extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userTextInput: "",
      listArray: ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
    };
    this.updateText = this.updateText.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      listArray: [...this.listArray, this.userTextInput]
    });
  }

  updateText(evt) {
    this.setState({
      userTextInput: evt.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="form-inline" id="usertodoinput">
          <TextBar function={this.updateText} compValue={this.state.userTextInput} />
          <AddButton function={this.handleClick} />
        </form>
        <ListEntry compValue={this.state.listArray} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserToDoInput;
```

As you can see in the code above, the **handleClick** function is triggered when the "ADD" button is clicked by the user, thus, resulting in the user's text input in the **TextBar** component, to be appended to the **listArray** state. This **listArray** array would then be mapped inside the **ListEntry** component into an ordered list.

The  works as it does map the **listArray** into an ordered list. I know this as I have three "tester" elements in the **listArray** array, that is, *test1, test2, test3*. And all of these "tester" elements are visibly converted to an ordered list.

However, when I view my **listArray** array after manually inputting a value into the text input and clicking the "ADD" button, I can see in my Chrome Extension for React that my **listArray** is not updated with the new appended value.

When I view my **handleClick** function, there does not seem to be any syntax errors, so what could be the reason for this error?

Thanks for the help

**UPDATE**

As suggested by one of the answerers, Prateek Thapa, below is my code for the TextBar, AddButton, ListEntry components, respectively.

TextBar component:

```
import React from "react";

class TextBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" className="form-control" id="textbar" placeholder="What I should get done today..." onChange={this.props.function} value={this.props.compValue} />
    );
  }
}

export default TextBar;
```

AddButton component:

```
import React from "react";

class AddButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="btn btn-primary mb-2" id="addbutton" onClick={this.props.function}>ADD</button>
    );
  }
}

export default AddButton;
```

ListEntry component:

```
import React from "react";

class ListEntry extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ol>
          {this.props.compValue.map((elem, i) => <li key = {i}>{elem}</li>)}
        </ol>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ListEntry;
```

Comment: Typo, missing `state` reference in both accesses? `listArray: [...this.listArray, this.userTextInput]` => `listArray: [...this.state.listArray, this.state.userTextInput]`. Looks like you mixed up a functional state update syntax a bit.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I changed that section of the code, but it still doesn't update the state of listArray.

Comment: How are you validating that state isn't updating? Are you able to reproduce this in a *running* codesandbox?

Comment: Maybe it's not validating, but I am viewing my code on my localhost and I am viewing my props through a Chrome Extension. The Extension shows that the props for the ListEntry component is just the initial listArray state with the tester elements even after triggering the handleClick function.

Comment: Are you referring to the react-dev-tools extension? You would/should be looking for state updates in `UserToDoInput` first, to ensure state is being updated, *then* start looking at the components state is being passed as a prop to.

Comment: Does the page refresh when you press the button? You could try to prevent default of the event in handleClick on the first line: `evt.preventDefault()` (You also need to add evt as a parameter to the function)

Comment: Right, I just checked again, and it does not show any updates the state in the UserToDoInput.

Comment: @A.Larsson Thank you! This solved the problem!

Comment: Also, thank you to everyone else, too. :)

Comment: @A.Larsson Could you please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Ah, I was also wondering if a button/form issue was involved here, but wanted to see more of the code first. The default `type` for `button` elements is `type="submit"`, which when within a `form` will make the form take the default `onSubmit` action. You can likely also just specify the button type to be `type="button"` to prevent this.

Comment: @pdsla112, will do! Glad to be able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the input field and button is within a form tag and the default behaviour from browsers is to interpret a button within a form as a `<input type="submit"/>` thus refreshing the page and all state is lost and the component is rerendered.

```
  handleClick(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault() // this line prevents the refresh from happening. 
    this.setState({
      listArray: [...this.listArray, this.userTextInput]
    });
  }
```

Another solution is just not to use the form element. It doesn't really serve a true purpose for things like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your typo from `this.listArray` to `this.state.listArray`

```
 handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      listArray: [...this.state.listArray, this.state.userTextInput]
    });
  }
```

You could also use the updater version. In this case, this.setState takes a function which gets the prevState as the parameter.

```
handleClick() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      listArray: [...prevState.listArray, this.state.userTextInput]
    }));
  }
```

Comment: I tried both your solutions, and the first one still doesn't update my state, and the second leads to a type error "prevState is not iterable"

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your `TextBar` and `AddButton` component. Please do post the code.

Comment: Even with the functional state update you still spread `prevState.listArray` into the new array.

Answer (score 1):

you have missed using state in setState

```
handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      listArray: [...this.state.listArray, this.state.userTextInput]
    });
  }
```

Comment: I've tried this too, and it sill doesn't updated the listArray state.

Comment: this must work... try to validate by rendering it on the screen instead of chrome extension